# Is it valid to calculate the difference between two odd ratios within the levels of a categorial variable in an ordinal logistic model?

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, ordinal-data, odds-ratio, variable

Supose you have an ordinal logistic model, with a dependent variable with 6 categories, being 6 the highest and 1 the reference.

I have one independent categorial variable, that I would like to compare within the levels and I am unsure about the procedure. I am wondering if is valid to compare the two levels in this way:

If the odd ratio are defined as $\exp(\beta_{15})=7.84$, for one level 5 of this variable, and $\exp(\beta_{14})=1.95$ for the level 4. Can I subtract the difference $7.84-1.95=5.89$ and argue that individuals in level 4 are $5.89$ times more likely to perform worse than individuals in level 5?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the interpretation of the difference of odds ratios, a difference of a multiplicative association is not multiplicative.

On the other hand, your "independent variable" is actually 5 variables. Each odds ratio is a contrast compared to the "referent" level. If you would like to test the hypothesis that one contrast is equal to all the others, you need to compare nested models. The likelihood ratio test is a common go-to for this kind of test.

If $\beta_1$ is the OR comparing X=2 to X=1, $\beta_2$ for X=3 vs X=1, and so on for k categories, the null hypothesis can be stated as:

$$\mathcal{H}_0 : \beta_1 = \beta_2 = \ldots = \beta_{k-1}\\
\mathcal{H}_1 : \text{At least one } \beta_i \text{ different. } i= 1, 2, \ldots, k-1.$$

For instance, if I create data according to:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- factor(sample(1:6, 1000, replace=T))
y <- rbinom(1000, 1, 0.4) ## no association

fit.full <- glm(y ~ x, family=binomial)
fit.null <- glm(y ~ I(x!=1), family=binomial)
library(lmtest)
lrtest(fit.full, fit.null) ## do not reject null of homogeneity of the OR

> fit.full

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = binomial)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2           x3           x4           x5           x6  
    -0.5805       0.1892       0.3573       0.2854       0.2820       0.1085  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  994 Residual
Null Deviance:      1351 
Residual Deviance: 1348     AIC: 1360
> fit.null

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ I(x != 1), family = binomial)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)  I(x != 1)TRUE  
      -0.5805         0.2448  

Degrees of Freedom: 999 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      1351 
Residual Deviance: 1350     AIC: 1354

Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ x
Model 2: y ~ I(x != 1)
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   6 -674.00                     
2   2 -674.75 -4 1.5093      0.825
```

Comment: Yes, I see, but this is a test to assess the statistical difference between the levels of the categorical independent variable. But what about the magnitute, can I follow my last procedure to assess the difference between the two levels?

Comment: Also this example is for a logistic model, and my question is about an ordinal logistic model, is your response equivalent?

Comment: @MarioGS Not necessarily. so your covariate is a binary or continuous covariate? and you do not think the proportional odds assumption may hold, but rather you think there is a threshold effect where if the fitted value exceeds a certain amount, it is randomly distributed among the higher order ordinal effects. Is that what you are saying? Ordinal logistic models do not yield multiple ORs for a single covariate. I think you need to give more detial.

Comment: my covariate is a categorical variable, as I writen above, the model is an ordinal logistic model with 6 categories. What I am asking is if I can say something about the difference in magnitude within levels of the categorical explanatory variable as explained above.

Comment: @MarioGS more details on what you mean by the "X" is categorical. Binary? Polytomous? Ordinal?

Comment: What I mean by X, as I written above is one independent categorial variable, you can assume that has five levels, it is not ordinal it is just nominal, the first category is taken as reference (level 1), and I would like to compare within the levels. So imagine that one odd ratio, of the level 5 $exp(\beta_{15})=7.84$, and for the level 4 is $exp(\beta{14})=1.95$, my question is can estimate the difference between these two categories $7.84−1.95=5.89$?